# A repeatable and scalable image? Is it possible?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Okay here's the deal,

I have a banner graphic that I'd like to stretch 100% of the width

**and**

Repeat-y down the length of my site.

Is it possible to do both?

Comment: not in every browser right?  and I want this to play across multiple browser types.  Or is css3 more generally accepted now?

Comment: html5 has support for vector images which scale without degradation of image quality.  Support is definitely not backwards compatible.

Comment: @CBRRacer If you are speaking of SVG, it's well supported on all browser (you have to use VML for most IE version, but a library like RaphealJS will take all the pain away).

Comment: @HoLyVieR I was speaking of the SVG and support is good for current browsers but SVG isn't supported by say IE5, IE6, IE7, FF2, FF3, etc... so it's not really backwards compatible. http://www.codedread.com/svg-support.php http://caniuse.com/#search=svg

Comment: @CBRRacer As I said before for IE6+, you can use VML which is vectorial drawing, but for IE. Also, SVG is supported in Firefox 3. That's pretty much all the support you need if you want to do vectorial drawing. In fact, you probably just should check RaphealJS : http://raphaeljs.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="background: url(https://www.google.com/adsense/static/en_US/images/234x60.gif) repeat-y;background-size:100% auto;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please view above code. You need to use 'background-size' to specify width of image to 100%.

Comment: `<div style="background: url("pix/gradient3.jpg") repeat-y;background-size:100% auto;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>` 
didn't work in either IE 9 or FF

Comment: changed `url("pix/gradient3.jpg")` to single quotes `url('pix/gradient3.jpg')`

Still no go.  That is to say, no background appears at all.

Comment: Above code works with FireFox 6.0.2. Check if your image exists.